# Does a Google Apps test domain works for groups?

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups

The reseller from whom I bought the Google Apps Business account gave me a domain for testing the accounts BEFORE migrating.

It is working fine, I’m able to send emails to accounts using this domain (if I send emails to the real adress they will end up in the current server I’m using, not in the Google Apps accout).

But when I send an email to a group address using this test domain, no email gets delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems groups cannot be created to respond to several domains at once - you have to choose which domain a group belongs to: 
http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.no/2011/07/create-groups-on-secondary-domains.html

The key phrase here is:

> ... choose the desired domain name from the dropdown ...

That would be the reason your group does not receive email sent to `group@testdomain.google.com`.

Comment: I didn´t do that before migrating. BUT now I´ve just created a new group and I have a dropdown menu for choosing the domain (assuming you have more then one). SO if you have your domain + test-domain you should have a dropdown menu to choose when creating the group.